# Slider - Why my prev button doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, animation, button, slider, slideshow

All is in the title!
The whole things work excepted a bug on the prev btn... 
If you've got any solutions, feel free to reply!

Thank you all.

---

```
$(function() {
var     timer;
function autoplay() { 
    $('.slideshow > li:gt(0)').hide();
    timer = setInterval(function() { 
         $('.slideshow > :first-child').fadeOut(500).next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slideshow');
    }, 5000);
}
autoplay();
$('#prev, #next').click(function() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'prev': {
            clearInterval(timer); autoplay();
            $('.slideshow > :last-child').fadeOut(500).prev().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slideshow');
        }
            break;
        case 'next': {
            clearInterval(timer); autoplay();
            $('.slideshow > :first-child').fadeOut(500).next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slideshow');
        }
            break;
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? What is the error?

Comment: you can see here : https://jsfiddle.net/pdh09v2m/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly find the solution ! Works perfectly

Code :

```
$(function() {
var     timer;
function autoplay() { 
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        $('.slideshow > :first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slideshow');
    }, 5000);
}
autoplay();
$('#prev, #next').click(function() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'prev':
            clearInterval(timer); autoplay(); 
            $('.slideshow > :first-child').fadeOut();
            $('.slideshow > :last-child').fadeIn().prependTo('.slideshow');
            break;
        case 'next':
            clearInterval(timer); autoplay();
            $('.slideshow > :first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slideshow');
            break;
    }});});
```

Thank you for support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your css that is not leting your arrow right to be showing add
this css to make it right :

```
.arrows {
 max-width: 800px;
 position: absolute;
 width:100%;
 top:50%;
 -webkit-transform:translate(-50%);
 -ms-transform:translate(-50%);
 transform:translate(-50%);
 left:50%;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  var timer;

  function autoplay() {
    $('.slideshow > li:gt(0)').hide();
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      $('.slideshow > :first-child').fadeOut(500).next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slideshow');
    }, 5000);
  }
  autoplay();
  $('#prev, #next').click(function() {
    switch (this.id) {
      case 'prev':
        {
          clearInterval(timer);
          autoplay();
          $('.slideshow > :last-child').fadeOut(500).prev().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slideshow');
        }
        break;
      case 'next':
        {
          clearInterval(timer);
          autoplay();
          $('.slideshow > :first-child').fadeOut(500).next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slideshow');
        }
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slideshow {
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.item img {
  width: 800px;
}

.arrows {
  max-width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
   top:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%);
   transform:translate(-50%);
   left:50%;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 7.5em!important;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.fa.fa-angle-right {
  float: right;
}

.fa:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="slidecontainer">
<div class="slideshow">
  <li class="item active"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x600">1</li>
  <li class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x300"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x600"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x300"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x600"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x300"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x600"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x300"></li>
</div>
<div class="arrows">
  <span id="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <span id="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why your script doesn't work? First of all, the approach you took is based on the solution, that the first node of the gallery is always visible. So, if the user presses next button, the script takes the first child in the slideshow:

```
$('.slideshow > :first-child')
```

*(BTW you should wrap the list items `<li></li>` with the unordered list `<ul></ul>` and adjust some CSS)*

then hides it: `fadeOut(500)`, takes the next node, shows it and appends the first (hidden) node at the end. Now let's see how the script looks when the user presses prev button:

```
$('.slideshow > :last-child').fadeOut(500).prev()
```

You take the last node, you fade it out (but it's already faded), and you take the previous node (which is the node before the last, also faded) to show it, which is wrong. Besides the fact, that you are fading already hidden node, the main problem is that:

**the nodes are a list, with the beginning and the end, this is not a cycle, so that the `prev()` from the first it's not the last, and the `next()` from the last it's not the first.**

What I did, is to use the CSS class "active" and to switch it on and off when the user pushes the next/prev buttons. So that you don't need to manipulate on nodes and append them, but toggle a CSS class, which is faster.

I've managed to correct it here (as I wrote, it'a a slightly different approach):
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sveg/7m5qcLvL/3/)

Besided that, the gallery isn't responsive, but that's a different topic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and explanations. Indeed it''s working but the fade transition when using prev/next isn'f smooth lke the autoplay transition. Look here what l wanna mean : https://jsfiddle.net/7m5qcLvL/5/